# VF page integration with LinkedIn

Tags: apex, visualforce

Followed Steps.

Linkedin developer Console -> created App -> with client ID and Secret.

Now I am making API calls to linked in with following access token.

> {"access_token":"AQWI0-2W3sRsKjQ6WiKuiTEn0sCkIcDdsfscqYXXAoqb3IDI0Ab4zvzzUoqiYalRcr7e6x8_JjjptYupSDMktgKrS_zjxOKGj7tysWody43yG3U_iKTAiyHLAAgYAspVdfds1DrlPh_5OvUammbAwTGSBN21Af-wc7527dpATUeslmLtesdfkxuvL9noEE","expires_in":5184000}

I want to retrieve Post and comments and likes from linkedin account.

I am using the official documentation of linkedin provided [Here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin/)

that call should be on URL

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json

is there should be:

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&**access_token**="AQWI0-2W3sRsKjQ6WiKuiTEn0sCkIcDdsfscqYXXAoqb3IDI0Ab4zvzzUoqiYalRcr7e6x8_JjjptYupSDMktgKrS_zjxOKGj7tysWody43yG3U_iKTAiyHLAAgYAspVdfds1DrlPh_5OvUammbAwTGSBN21Af-wc7527dpATUeslmLtesdfkxuvL9noEE"

Or anything else?
Please suggest.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: MAM i am facing issue of below error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the following URL : https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&access_token="AQWI0-2W3sRsKjQ6WiKuiTEn0sCkIcDdsfscqYXXAoqb3IDI0Ab4zvzzUoqiYalRcr7e6x8_JjjptYupSDMktgKrS_zjxOKGj7tysWody43yG3U_iKTAiyHLAAgYAspVdfds1DrlPh_5OvUammbAwTGSBN21Af-wc7527dpATUeslmLtesdfkxuvL9noEE"

It should work fine repacing '~' with '%7E'

Please mark this as resolved if this resolves your issue.

Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: `{ "errorCode": 0, "message": "Unsupported POST target {/v1/people/%7E/shares}", "requestId": "494ONL7LQD", "status": 405, "timestamp": 1477309430969 }`

Comment: Thanks for ans. vipul . my POST request was :- https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/%7E/shares?format=json&access_token=AQWI0-2W3sRsKjQ6WiKuiTEn0sCkIcDdsfscqYXXAoqb3IDI0Ab4zvzzUoqiYalRcr7e6x8_JjjptYupSDMktgKrS_zjxOKGj7tysWody43yG3U_iKTAiyHLAAgYAspVdfds1DrlPh_5OvUammbAwTGSBN21Af-wc7527dpATUeslmLtesdfkxuvL9noEE

Comment: api.linkedin.com/v1/people/%7E/shares?format=json&access_token=AQWI0-2W3sRsKjQ6WiKuiTEn0sCkIcDdsfscqYXXAoqb3IDI0Ab4zvzzUoqiYalRcr7e6x8_JjjptYupSDMktgKrS_zjxOKGj7tysWody43yG3U_iKTAiyHLAAgYAspVdfds1DrlPh_5OvUammbAwTGSBN21Af-wc7527dpATUeslmLtesdfkxuvL9noEE

Comment: Have you tried like this :                                                                                Http h = new Http();
    String postParam ='';
    String method = 'POST';
string sharequery='http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates/key=UPDATE-c1756-5902360166031974400/is-liked';
    HttpRequest sharequery_req= new HttpRequest();   
    sharequery_req.setMethod(method);
    sharequery_req.setBody(body); 
    sharequery_req.setEndpoint(sharequery.replace('~','%7E'));
    sharequery_req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

Comment: Error:- Access to shares denied

Comment: `api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?updateKey=UPDATE-537543822-6196586659644039168&oauth2_access_token=AQXvtZAbIkUrUq9_KUlpEaWLzoqaE64FpOjfEm0MCjCRKkfqJpaxyXaubvmovnGQdNGAQjnpa-1dVcn7qYc_H7z8irWBm-TZQQN5Ag_xI5WTgIzDMWTChndi72Hv6MTkF5hhQbDtBcTvs_EjSakj9q9FCIMSDseZei5tcOR0JbxUvzauba4&format=json`

Comment: Also tried :- `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates?updateKey=UPDATE-537543822-6196586659644039168&oauth2_access_token=AQXvtZAbIkUrUq9_KUlpEaWLzoqaE64FpOjfEm0MCjCRKkfqJpaxyXaubvmovnGQdNGAQjnpa-1dVcn7qYc_H7z8irWBm-TZQQN5Ag_xI5WTgIzDMWTChndi72Hv6MTkF5hhQbDtBcTvs_EjSakj9q9FCIMSDseZei5tcOR0JbxUvzauba4&format=json`

Comment: Output:- Access to network denied :)

Comment: Have you defined the scope ??

Comment: I think you haven't mentioned the Scope of the request. Grab the Details from the following link : https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition                      Try adding: scope: r_network                                                                                                OR                                                                                                                              You need to make an request to linked in via vetted API Access form when they approved then you can update data.

Comment: Can you suggest writen code for sharing post on linkedin through Salesforce. i have access token retrieved Profile data But could not get code to post on linkedin.

Answer (score 0):

You could test the REST API URLs in the REST Console for LinkedIn at:
https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console

This is what I use for LinkedIn integration

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key:   ******
  onLoad:    onLinkedInLoad, OnLinkedInAuth
  authorize: true
  lang:      en_US
</script>

<script>
  function OnLinkedInAuth() {
    IN.API.Profile("me").fields(["firstName","headline","positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker))","educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes)"])
    .result(function(result) {
       console.log(result)
    })
    IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares").result(callback);
  }

  function callback(){}
</script>
```